# PowerBI: Filter Using URL Query String Parameter in report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I applied advance filter in PowerBI desktop, It is working. Similarly, I want to apply "Contains" or "In" operator to filter a report using URL Query String Parameter. I want to filter with delimitated value. "eq" operator is working but "in/contains" operator is not working.

I tried like this:
`lstReportFilter.Add(string.Format("&filter=Sheet1/TPId in |181|"));`

I have taken reference from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters

Can you please correct me on what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried with round bracket, but still its not working. The column have data with pipes, so I need to include pipe while filtering.

`lstReportFilter.Add(string.Format("&filter=Sheet1/TPId in (|181|)"));`

`lstReportFilter.Add(string.Format("&filter=Sheet1/TPId in ('|181|')"));`

[PowerBI column data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Adp0.png)

Comment: You used pipes instead of brackets to surround the values.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I also tried this and its not working. I updated the question too.

Comment: 'in' operation means that **the value** of the cell is in the list of values provided. `in ('|181|')` doesn't mean that the filter will return the rows, where the cell **contains** |181|, but the rows, where the cell **is** |181|. You are looking for **contains** operation, not **in** operator. The OData filter for `contains` is like `$filter=contains(Sheet1/TPId, '|181|')`, but as you can see it isn't in the [list of supported operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#operators).

Comment: @AndreyNikolov you exactly got my point what I want. So what you think, there is no way to use contains?

Answer (score 0):

IN Operator expects a comma seperated list of primitive values or a expression

eg:

```
~/Products?$filter=Name in ('Milk', 'Cheese')
~/Products?$filter=Name in RelevantProductNames
~/Products?$filter=ShipToAddress/CountryCode in MyShippers/Regions
~/Products?$filter=Name in Fully.Qualified.Namespace.MostPopularItemNames
```

It seems like your use case is the first example, but if you don't have multiple values you can simply use the EQ Operator
like: `filter=Sheet1/TPId eq |181|`

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/odata/webapi/in-operator

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters

Comment: I have tried it using 'eq' operator but it is not working for me. I have uploaded dummy dataset image https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Adp0.png